# I cant init Google Cloud SDK on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine, ubuntu, permissions

I downloaded Google Cloud SDK for python on my Ubuntu. (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux#before-you-begin)

Then I followed the steps from the page but when I run

```
gcloud init
```

I get this

> Could not setup log file in /home/ariel/.config/gcloud/logs, (IOError:
>   [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/home/ariel/.config/gcloud/logs/2016.05.25/11.54.37.438036.log')
>   Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of
>   gcloud.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.init) Failed to create the default configuration.
>   Ensure your have the correct permissions on:
>   [/home/ariel/.config/gcloud/configurations].   Could not create
>   directory [/home/ariel/.config/gcloud/configurations]: Permission
>   denied.
>
> Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent
>   directory.

**PS:** Then I found this other file https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python (**seems to be the same but it is 40.2MB and the one I used was 7.5MB**)

Thanks !
Ariel

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The user **gcbirzan** responded my questions at an irc channel (which I recommend), it is **#appengine** on **irc.freenode.net**

I had to run this:

```
sudo chown ariel -R /home/ariel/.config/gcloud
```

I also leave the transcription of the chat here:

> [14:12] **Q:** Hello
>
> [14:13] **Q:** I am just beggining with app engine, and for instance, anyone could tell me what is the difference between this file((https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux#before-you-begin)) and this one ((https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python)) (seems to be the same but it is 40.2MB and the one I used was 7.5MB)
>
> [14:15] **A:** Google cloud sdk is gcloud and friends, you need it for flex and other google cloud platform stuff.
>
> [14:15] **A:** The appengine sdk is the one that comes with a local dev server and all the other stuff, and is probably what you want
>
> [14:15] **A:** well. go wild, get both
>
> [14:16] **Q:** ok
>
> [14:16] **Q:** thanks
>
> [14:16] **Q:** and could you please help me with this ? [I cant init Google Cloud SDK on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441174/i-cant-init-google-cloud-sdk-on-ubuntu)
>
> [14:17] **A:** sudo chown ariel -R /home/ariel/.config/gcloud
>
> [14:19] **Q:** it works !

Comment: I had the same problem.  Looks like a bug in their installation, to leave my own config directory as root-only

Comment: Great job, Ariel!

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1:**

You should run

```
sudo gcloud init
```

Instead of `gcloud init`

**Option 2:**

Give owner permissions for your user:

```
sudo chown -R <username> ~/.config
```

Comment: do not use more sudo to fix too much sudo.  it is cancerous.